# Slidebar Tab and Slidebar not in sync when toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning Jquery.

I'm having problems with a slidebar.  When I hit the Tab to open it, the Sidebar Tab and the sidebar itself doesn't move in sync.

The effect I want to implement is to make the tab look like it is attached to the Slidetab when it is animating.

Can someone help me with this?

here is a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/cb1tzLxd/36/)

below is my code in a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slideOutTab').on("click", function(){
    //$("#facetsSlide").toggleClass('show');
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = {direction: 'right'};
    var duration = 500;

    $("#facetsSlide").toggle(effect, options, duration);
    $('.slideOutTab').toggleClass('showSlideOut');
  });
  
  $('.closebtn').on("click", function(){
    $("#facetsSlide").toggle('show');
    $('.slideOutTab').toggleClass('showSlideOut');
  });
});
```

```css
#facetsSlide {
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #FFF;
   position: absolute;
right: 0px;
border: #d3d3d3;
border-right: none;
display: none;
}

#facetsSlide.show {
  transform: inherit;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

.closebtn {
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  color: black;
        }


.showSlideOut {
  right: 300px !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
}


.slideOutTab {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  /*left: -40px;*/
  right: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 40px;
  /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);*/
  background: #fff;
  border: #d3d3d3;
  border-right: none;
}

.slideOutTab div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 70px;
  top: 90px;
 color: red;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  writing-mode: lr-tb;
}



@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #facetsSlide {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    display: block; }
    #facetsSlide .slideOutTab {
      position: absolute; } }

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  #facetsSlide {
    display: none;
    /*  transform: translateX(-100%);*/ } }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .content {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px; }
  #facetsSlide {
    border: none; }
  .slideOutTab {
    display: none; }
  .closebtn {
    display: none; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #facetsSlide {
    border: none; }
  .content {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px; } }

@media (min-width: 1999px) {
  #facetsSlide {
    margin-right: 22vw; } }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>Tímarit</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="col-md-3 " id="facetsSlide">
            <a href="#" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
            <article class="card-group-item">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <h6 class="title">TExt</h6>
               </header>
               <div class="filter-content">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <ul>
                        <li>Text</li>
                        <li>Text</li>
                        <li>Text</li>
                        <li>Text</li>
                     </ul>
                  
                  </div>
                  <!-- card-body.// -->
               </div>
            </article>
            <!-- card-group-item.// -->
            <article class="card-group-item">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <h6 class="title">text sector</h6>
               </header>
               <div class="filter-content">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <ul>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <!-- card-body.// -->
               </div>
            </article>
            <!-- card-group-item.// -->
         </div>
         <div class="slideOutTab">
            <div>
               <p>open sidebar</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The concept is wrong, better use css to animate both, script only to toggle class. Also, you can put the "open sidebar" html together with sidebar menu, do not separate them, so they will both animate together.

Answer (score 1):

You needed some transition for the `.slideOutTab` section

```
.slideOutTab {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    /*left: -40px;*/
    right: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 40px;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);*/
    background: #fff;
    border: #d3d3d3;
    border-right: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slideOutTab').on("click", function(){
    //$("#facetsSlide").toggleClass('show');
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = {direction: 'right'};
    var duration = 500;

    $("#facetsSlide").toggle(effect, options, duration);
    $('.slideOutTab').toggleClass('showSlideOut');
  });
  
  $('.closebtn').on("click", function(){
    $("#facetsSlide").toggle('show');
    $('.slideOutTab').toggleClass('showSlideOut');
  });
});
```

```css
#facetsSlide {
 max-width: 300px;
 background: #FFF;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 border: #d3d3d3;
 border-right: none;
 display: none;
}

#facetsSlide.show {
 transform: inherit;
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
}

.closebtn {
 top: 0px;
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-left: 220px;
 color: black;
}

.showSlideOut {
 right: 300px !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
 transition: all 500ms;
}

.slideOutTab {
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 1000;
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 /*left: -40px;*/
 right: 0px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 40px;
 /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);*/
 background: #fff;
 border: #d3d3d3;
 border-right: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.slideOutTab div {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 right: 70px;
 top: 90px;
 color: red;
 width: 180px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
 writing-mode: lr-tb;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #facetsSlide {
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
 }
 #facetsSlide .slideOutTab {
  position: absolute;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
 #facetsSlide {
  display: none;
  /*  transform: translateX(-100%);*/
 }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
 }
 #facetsSlide {
  border: none;
 }
 .slideOutTab {
  display: none;
 }
 .closebtn {
  display: none;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 #facetsSlide {
  border: none;
 }
 .content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1999px) {
 #facetsSlide {
  margin-right: 22vw;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>Tímarit</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="col-md-3 " id="facetsSlide">
            <a href="#" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
            <article class="card-group-item">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <h6 class="title">TExt</h6>
               </header>
               <div class="filter-content">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <ul>
                        <li>Text</li>
                        <li>Text</li>
                        <li>Text</li>
                        <li>Text</li>
                     </ul>
                  
                  </div>
                  <!-- card-body.// -->
               </div>
            </article>
            <!-- card-group-item.// -->
            <article class="card-group-item">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <h6 class="title">text sector</h6>
               </header>
               <div class="filter-content">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <ul>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                        <li>more txt</li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <!-- card-body.// -->
               </div>
            </article>
            <!-- card-group-item.// -->
         </div>
         <div class="slideOutTab">
            <div>
               <p>open sidebar</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I added `transition` to the class, but it is still not behaving like it is attached to the Sidebar

Comment: it's animation type issue, normally CSS transition is a linear transition but jquery is ease timing. you can use setTimeout() for fixed this